# Filtering out data returned by AWS Textract function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I have extracted data returned by Textract AWS function. The return data type of this Textract function is of the following type:

```
{
   "AnalyzeDocumentModelVersion": "string",
   "Blocks": [ 
      { 
         "BlockType": "string",
         "ColumnIndex": number,
         "ColumnSpan": number,
         "Confidence": number,
         "EntityTypes": [ "string" ],
         "Geometry": { 
            "BoundingBox": { 
               "Height": number,
               "Left": number,
               "Top": number,
               "Width": number
            },
            "Polygon": [ 
               { 
                  "X": number,
                  "Y": number
               }
            ]
         },
         "Id": "string",
         "Page": number,
         "Relationships": [ 
            { 
               "Ids": [ "string" ],
               "Type": "string"
            }
         ],
         "RowIndex": number,
         "RowSpan": number,
         "SelectionStatus": "string",
         "Text": "string"
      }
   ],
   "DocumentMetadata": { 
      "Pages": number
   },
   "JobStatus": "string",
   "NextToken": "string",
   "StatusMessage": "string",
   "Warnings": [ 
      { 
         "ErrorCode": "string",
         "Pages": [ number ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have extracted the Blocks from this data by the following code :

```
var d = null;
...<Some Code Here>...
d = data.Blocks;
console.log(d);
```

which gives an output as an array of JSON objects. An example of the extracted text is given below :

```
[...{ BlockType: 'WORD',
    Confidence: 99.7286376953125,
    Text: '2000.00',
    Geometry: { BoundingBox: [Object], Polygon: [Array] },
    Id: '<ID here>',
    Page: 1 }, ...]
```

I want to extract only the Text field and see it as the only output. How do I start about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably misinterpreting your question but if what you need is to extract the value of the Text field of each object in the data array, please take a look at the following example

```js
const data = [
  {
    BlockType: "WORD",
    Confidence: 99.7286376953125,
    Text: "2000.00",
    Geometry: { BoundingBox: {}, Polygon: [] },
    Id: "<ID here>",
    Page: 1,
  },
];

const output = data.map(({ Text: text }) => text);

console.log(output);
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: yes that is what I meant and your interpretation is correct. I will try out your code.

Comment: That good. If your test went well I would appreciate it if you mark the answer as correct

Comment: @Mario......yeah sure will do that. Just one last question- I want to check which of the text item starts with a letter. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you provide an example data with text item starting with letter

Comment: it is actually 6 character string. It starts with three letters and three digits. Something like XYZ123.

Comment: when you mention 'I want to check which of the text item starts with a letter'. You mean you need to filter the data by only those whose Text property starts with text?

Comment: Yes.......anyways thanks for your answer. Never mind, actually I figured out an idea to solve the filter out issue using Regex expressions. Cheers!

Comment: @Mario Hi there, I see you are knowledgeable on this topic. Could you please help with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499160/aws-textract-key-value-pair-java-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception